# How to search for String in C language

Tags: c, file-handling

I am developing a student management system in C, but I can't seem to accomplish the search function. Writing to a file works fine but searching by name is not working. Nothing happens when I enter the name and the program exits.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    int id;
    char name[10];
    int semester;
};

int main(void) {
    char name[10], c[100];
    struct student s;
    FILE *fp;
    int choice;

    printf("Enter 1 to Add record\nEnter 2 to Search \n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            fp = fopen("std.txt", "a");
            printf("\nEnter id: ");
            scanf("%d", &s.id);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter name: ");
            scanf("%s", &s.name);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter semester: ");
            scanf("%d", &s.semester);
            fflush(stdin);

            fprintf(fp, "\nId: %d\tName: %s\tSemester: %d\n", s.id,s.name,s.semester);
            fclose(fp);
            break;

        case 2:
            fp=fopen("std.txt","r");
            printf("ENTER THE NAME ");
            scanf("%s",&name);
            while(feof(fp)) {
                if(strcmp(name, s.name) == 0) {
                    printf("\n\t%d\t %s\t %d", s.id, s.name, s.semester);
                    getch();
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
            getch();
            break;

        case 3:
            exit(1);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `while (feof(fp)) {` Huh?!

Comment: (1) You don't need to keep opening and closing the file.  (2) Why `while(feof(fp))` is wrong has beeen covered here a million times. (3) You know what would be good in the while loop? A file read, maybe?

Comment: `id` should be primary key compare id only

Comment: even if i change my while loop to this "while(fread(&s,sizeof(s),1,fp))" it doesnt work. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Note that `getch` is not a standard library function nor is `conio.h` a standard library header. Use `getchar` instead.

Comment: `fflush` works only on output streams. `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Reading the structure is not from the file. It is to use the fread and fwrite as my suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually reading the line into the student structure.  You probably meant to `fgets` or `scanf` each line in the file and load it into the `struct student s`.

Answer (score 0):

sample of use fwrite and fread

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    int id;
    char name[10];
    int semester;
};

int main(void) {
    char name[10], c[100];
    struct student s;
    FILE *fp;
    int choice;

while(1){
    printf("Enter 1 to Add record\nEnter 2 to Search \nEnter 3 to Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            fp = fopen("std.txt", "ab");
            printf("\nEnter id: ");
            scanf("%d", &s.id);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter name: ");
            scanf("%s", &s.name);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nEnter semester: ");
            scanf("%d", &s.semester);
            fflush(stdin);

            //fprintf(fp, "\nId: %d\tName: %s\tSemester: %d\n", s.id,s.name,s.semester);
            fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, fp);
            fclose(fp);
            break;

        case 2:
            fp=fopen("std.txt","rb");
            printf("ENTER THE NAME ");
            scanf("%9s", name);
            getchar();
            while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, fp)==1) {
                if(strcmp(name, s.name) == 0) {
                    printf("\n\t%d\t %s\t %d\n", s.id, s.name, s.semester);
                    break;
                }
            }
            fclose(fp);
            break;

        case 3:
            exit(1);
    }
}
    getchar();
}
```